# Equivalent in English when you ask for something back

Tags: meaning

How do you say when...You lent some money and are asking it back...

In portuguese we can say "Adriano está me cobrando os 10 dollars."

But I am not sure if I can say this in English "Adriano is charging me."

I would like to know if there is an equivalent expression to be used as the example.

Comment: *collecting*. A person who does this for clients is called a *collector*.

Comment: The lender is *calling in* the loan. He/she is calling for the repayment of the loan by the borrower.

Answer (score 1):

We generally put the emphasis on the one who was lent the money, that is, the one who *owes*:
"I owe Andriano 10 dollars". One could also say, "Andriano expects 10 dollars from me." - but it may be helpful (or necessary, depending on context) to put it this way: "Andriano expects 10 dollars back from me," which is a perfectly comfortable way of implying the money was lent and is expected to be returned/paid.

Comment: Perfectly understood, there is no emphasis like the way I had expressed.